# cmd filename as command in cmd.exe

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am probably missing some lingo to find the answer to a question which I believe has probably been posted already, hence my apologies beforehand.

I wrote a cmd script (myCmdFileName.cmd) that changes some IP configurations using netsh. To run it from cmd, I have to be in the same folder of the script and write in the console myCmdFileName.cmd.

As you know, netsh is a commandline application itself, as I would use it like:

```
netsh [-flags] [-configs]
```

What I would like to do is to have my cmd file be called just like as if it was an application like netsh, not worrying about whether I am in the file folder, so like this:

```
myCmdFileName [-flags] [-arguments]
```

How would I go about doing that in Windows cmd?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to run `myCmdFileName` from anywhere, either it's parent folder needs to be [added to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9546324/adding-directory-to-path-environment-variable-in-windows) `%PATH%`, or you can move it / create a symbolic link to it in a folder that already is in `%PATH%`.